# Filtering core data results using predicates

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to core data and I am trying to implement its relationship .I have two table

I have created a one-to-many relation between IDUSUNP and Wouni. Now lets say,IDUSUNP has 1000 records and Wouni has 100 user specific records.I want to filter the records from wouni using assetid as predicate that should be same as the assetid of IDUSUNP plus it should have userid as predicate also.
I mean,I want to get the records from wouni having asset id same as IDUSUNP' asset ids and userid="1000".I am not able to use this as predicate.Kindly give your suggestions and help me to solve.

Comment: Please show the predicates you have tried.

Comment: Sir, I am having problem in using predicates.I have done till adding relationships but not able to understand the predicate to be used here.

Comment: @Prez please check the answer, ask questions if you face further problem

Comment: @Prez please give feedback if it solves your problem or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the required data you can use this predicate,

For **Objective-C**

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"assetid = idusunp.assetid AND idusunp.userid = 1000"];
[fetchRequest setPredicate: predicate];
```

For **Swift**

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "assetid = idusunp.assetid AND idusunp.userid = 1000")
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
```

This predicate  will fetch the records from wouni whose assetid is equal to assetid of idusunp and where userid is equal to 1000.